# Custom javascript confirm dialog box

Tags: javascript, dialog, confirm

I have a function called `showModalConfirmDialog` that creates a custom javascript made dialog box with two buttons Yes/No and dims the background. Now in my functions I want to call that function like:

```
var outcome = showModalConfirmDialog('Are you sure?');
```

and I want to react depending on the button clicked;

```
if(outcome == true){
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

The buttons return true/false.
Javascript code:

```
button1.onclick = function(evt){
    return true;
};

button2.onclick = function(evt){
    return false;
};
```

I don't know what I am missing, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the problem? Doesn't it show?

Comment: It does show, but I want it to react just like the javascript confirm function. I will explain detailed; lets say I have a function called `save();` in this function I am calling the above code `var outcome = showModalConfirmDialog('Are you sure?');` and depending on the `outcome` I am doing some other stuff, the problem is that the save function is not waiting for the user's response/click, it is return undefined.

Comment: I mean, do I have to block something to stop executing other scripts and wait for the user's click? @LuigiEdlCarno

Comment: You CANNOT do this. The built-in `confirm()` is special in that it executes synchronously. All other JS code will execute asynchronously, or block the UI (i.e. the user will not be able to interact). The solution is to either provide the `showModalConfirmDialog()` with `ok()`/`cancel()` callbacks, or have it return a [promise](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/) ([jQuery implementation](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reproduce the behaviour of the native modal. Instead you could use callbacks.

This way :

```
function showModalConfirmDialog(msg, handler) {
    button1.onclick = function(evt){
        handler(true);
    };
    button2.onclick = function(evt){
        handler(false);
    };
}
showModalConfirmDialog('Are you sure?', function (outcome) { 
    alert(outcome ? 'yes' : 'no'); 
});
```

Or this way :

```
function showModalConfirmDialog(msg, confirmHandler, denyHandler) {
    button1.onclick = confirmHandler;
    button2.onclick = denyHandler;
}
showModalConfirmDialog(
    'Are you sure?', 
    function () { alert('yes'); }, 
    function () { alert('no'); }
);
```